# How to bind JSON data after Kendo Grid Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid on a page wich is initialized with the following code:

```
$.post("@Url.Action("kendoGetJson", "MyOpsUser")", function (col) {
        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid($.parseJSON(col));
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
           {
               transport: {
                   read: {
                       url: '@Url.Action("MyTaskOpsPopulate", "MyOpsUser", new { filterType = "0", user = "toto", urgencyState = "{\"Urgent\":true,\"Standard\":true,\"OnHold\":true}" })',
                       contentType: "application/json",
                       dataType: "json"
                   }
               },
               schema: {
                   data: "Value"
               },
               type: "json",
               serverPaging: false,
               serverFiltering: true,
               serverSorting: false
           }
        );

        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var dataSource = dataSource.read();
        grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

The grid definition is the following:

```
{"height": 550,
"groupable": true,
"sortable": true,
"pageable": {
    "refresh": true,
    "pageSizes": true,
    "buttonCount": 5
},
"columns": [
    {
        "field": "Titre"
    },
    {
        "field": "Prix"
    }
]}
```

The data JSON that I want to bind to my grid:

```
{"Value": [
    {
        "Titre": "hey",
        "Prix": 12
    },
    {
        "Titre": "hello",
        "Prix": 25
    }
]}
```

I get the following error in the console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined".

The data file is bind after the grid load and not in the definition file because I need to generate the data's JSON dynamically.

I can't figure it out how to make this work, if someone could help, it would be great...

Comment: I don't see why to bind the dataSource after grid initialization since you can set it in the grid options and it will request for remote data as well. Did you tried setting the dataSource in the grid properties ? Besides, it is possible that the dataSource's request return empty data ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found how to fix it !

$.post("@Url.Action("kendoGetJson", "MyOpsUser")", function (col) {

```
        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid($.parseJSON(col));

        $.post("@Url.Action("MyOpsUserPopulate", "MyOpsUser", new { filterType = "0", user = "toto", urgencyState = "{\"Urgent\":true,\"Standard\":true,\"OnHold\":true}" })", function (JsonData) {
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            var datasource = grid.dataSource;
            datasource.data(JsonData);
        });
```

This worked for me. Thanks for the help !

Comment: hey my problem is relevant can you answer please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171551/how-to-use-data-from-model-to-bind-as-kendo-datasource        m using ASP.Net MVC