# How to use data from Model to bind as kendo datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

i have an empty div that i want to initialize into a kendo grid using data from Model..it should be something like the following but i am unable to load data

```
$("#mapsDiv").kendoGrid({
    sortable: true,
    dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                                   read:"/Home/About",
                                   dataType: "odata"
                               },
                    pageSize: 5
                },
    pageable: true,
    resizable: true,
    columnMenu: true,
    scrollable:true,
    navigatable: true,
    editable: "incell"
});
```

**About.cshtml**

```
@model List<KendoExample.Entities.ShortStudent>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive" id="mapsDiv">        
</div>
```

My **Home Controller** is as follows

```
List<ShortStudent> students = new List<ShortStudent>();

ShortStudent student1 = new ShortStudent();
student1.birthdate = new DateTime(1999, 4, 30);
student1.classname = "1B";
student1.firstname = "Fredie";
student1.surname = "Fletcher";
student1.studentid = 1;

ShortStudent student2 = new ShortStudent();
student2.birthdate = new DateTime(2010, 5, 4);
student2.classname = "1B";
student2.firstname = "Lee";
student2.surname = "Hobbs";
student2.studentid = 2;

students.Add(student1);
students.Add(student2);

return View(students);
```

I have seen examples using json but not odata...

Also, there are examples to use it like

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<MeetingViewModel>()
.Name("scheduler")
.Editable(false)
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Custom()
    .Batch(true)
    .Schema(schema => schema
        .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id(f => f.MeetingID);
            m.Field("title", typeof(string)).DefaultValue("No title").From("Title");
            m.Field("start", typeof(DateTime)).From("Start");
            m.Field("end", typeof(DateTime)).From("End");
            m.Field("description", typeof(string)).From("Description");
            m.Field("recurrenceID", typeof(int)).From("RecurrenceID");
            m.Field("recurrenceRule", typeof(string)).From("RecurrenceRule");
            m.Field("recurrenceException", typeof(string)).From("RecurrenceException");
            m.Field("isAllDay", typeof(bool)).From("IsAllDay");
            m.Field("startTimezone", typeof(string)).From("StartTimezone");
            m.Field("endTimezone", typeof(string)).From("EndTimezone");
        }))
    .Transport(new {
        //the ClientHandlerDescriptor is a special type that allows code rendering as-is (not as a string)
        read = new Kendo.Mvc.ClientHandlerDescriptor() {HandlerName = "customRead" }
    })
)
)
```

which i am unable to understand/implement so please ignore this kind of a solution.

Currently i see a grid footer that says (1 - 2 of 4852 items) without any header or content(datarows) on my screen. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

```
  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
       {
           transport: {
               read: {
                   url: '@Url.Action("About", "Home")',
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   dataType: "json"
               }
           },
           schema: {
               model: {
                   fields: {
                       firstname: { type: "string" },
                       surname: { type: "string" },
                       birthdate: { type: "date" },
                       classname: { type: "string" }
                   }
               }
           },
           type: "json",
           serverPaging: false,
           serverFiltering: true,
           serverSorting: false
       }
    );

 $("#mapsDiv")
        .kendoGrid(
    {

        sortable: true,
        dataSource: {

            transport: {
                read: dataSource
            },
            pageSize: 2
        },
        pageable: true,
        resizable: false,
        columnMenu: true,
        scrollable:true,
        navigatable: true,
        editable: "incell",
        columns:[{
            field: "firstname",
        },{
            field: "surname",
        },{
            field: "classname",
        },{
            field: "age",
        }]
    });
```

**HomeController**

```
 public ActionResult About()
    {
   ....
     return View(students);
 }
```

Now the grid with header is there but no data is present..
If i change action to json, it returns plain json on the page

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
   ....
     return Json(students, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Comment: Firstly you haven't added any fields to your grid.

Comment: i have now added columns as suggested but now only header is available data is still not there, probably its reading something else as data because page footer shows total 5014 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what i found what should have been straight forward :)

```
var values = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model));

 $("#MapDetails")
        .kendoGrid(
    {
        sortable: true,
        dataSource: {
            data:values,
            pageSize: 2
        },
        pageable: true,
        resizable: false,
        columnMenu: true,
        scrollable:true,
        navigatable: true,
        editable: "incell",
        columns:[{
            field: "firstname",
        },{
            field: "surname",
        },{
            field: "classname",
        },{
            field
        : "age",
        }]

    });
```

Comment: Sigh, this is exactly what i said you should do.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried adding the fields to the grid?

```
$("#mapsDiv")
    .kendoGrid(
{

    sortable: true,
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
           read:"/Home/About",
           dataType: "odata"
        },
        pageSize: 5
    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            field: "classname",
                            title: "Class Name"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "firstname",
                            title: "First name"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "surname",
                            title: "Last name"
                        }
                    ],
    pageable: true,
    resizable: true,
    columnMenu: true,
    scrollable:true,
    navigatable: true,
    editable: "incell"

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just visit demo of telerik. Try following. Hope to help, my friend. Or you can visit this link to refer more: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/remote-data-binding.

```
$("#mapsDiv")
        .kendoGrid(
    {

        sortable: true,
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
               read:"/Home/About",
               dataType: "odata"
            },
            pageSize: 5
        },
       schema: {
                 model: {
                        fields: {
                             studentid: { type: "number" },
                             birthdate : { type: "date" },
                             classname : { type: "string" },
                             firstname : { type: "date" },
                             surname : { type: "string" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
        pageable: true,
        resizable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        scrollable:true,
        navigatable: true,
        editable: "incell"

    });
```

Comment: I changed My controller to return json(students), now it shows me plain the json on page instead of any UI/ grid

Comment: @Samra: You need to change dataType: "odata" to "json". Visit this link to refer more, my friend: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/overview

Comment: Hi Tomato i did change from odata to json you can see my update in the original post..i am still stuck..appreciate any help thanks